# OZON API смена статуса необработанной заявки

Tags: python, api

Не могу решить проблему.
Делаю запрос к апи озон селлера. Чтобы изменить статус доставки товара. Выводится {"result":[{"posting_number":"32575222-9229-7", "result":false, "error":"TRANSITION_IS_NOT_POSSIBLE"}]}. Хотя и запрос правильный и posting_number верный передаётся. Но всё равно выдаёт ошибку. Мои догадки: это происходит потому, что я передаю статус отправки delivered посылке со статусом delivering. И скорее всего система видит, что посылка не доставлена и поэтому не может изменить статус. Может кто знает почему?

```
url = 'https://api-seller.ozon.ru/v2/fbs/posting/delivering'
headers = {'Client-Id': '',
           'Api-Key': ''}
body = {'posting_number': ['32575222-9229-7']}
response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, json=body)
print(response.text)
```